# VBA check if value in list

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change my code below to check if the value is in my list? ALso, How can I change the for C = 1 to 1000 to make it automatically check from 1 to n where n is the total amount of columns?

```
Dim c As Long, r1 As Range
arrList = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
For c = 1 To 1000
    If Cells(1, c).Value = "A" Then
        Cells(1, c).Select
```

Comment: You just loop `arrList`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50649967/9245853 for how to find the last column.

Comment: Also see [how to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).